# Passing arrays into a method (java)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, declaration

I am currently writing a code to do a Knight's Tour. I am trying to pass a double array (the board) into a method and I get an error that an  is expected.  I do not know how I am supposed to declare it(array doesn't work), or if that's wrong entirely.
Here is the code I am currently stuck on.

```
 public void makeBoard(Board,int column, int row){
     for (i=1;i<=column;i++)
     {
         for  (j=1;j<=row;j++)
         {
              Board[i][j] = "x";
         }
     }
     Board[1][1] = "1";
     xpos = 1;
     ypos = 1;
 }
```

Mainly the declaration. Board is a double array.

Comment: You didn't say what is the first parameter's type..

Comment: `Board is a double array.` -> You mean an array of array?

Comment: it is not called double array, it is 2d array.

Comment: Otherwise regarding this code: You are aware that arrays in Java are zero-indexed, right? I believe what you wanted was `Board[0][0]` and `for(int i=0;...`, `for(int j=0;...`

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the type of the parameter.

```
public void makeBoard(String[][] Board, int column, int row){
```

Notes:

1. The name of the type is *not* a double array. The word `double` is the name of a different type in Java. It means a [double precision floating point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). You don't have any doubles anywhere in your code.
2. The standard naming convention is to use camel case for parameter names. You should write `board` instead of `Board`.
3. Arrays are [0-indexed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) in Java. Your loops should start from 0, not 1.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Sadly I got a lot more errors, but I know how to pass in arrays thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

In a java method, parameter is made up with parameter type and name. For `int` column, `int` is the type and column is the name. Therefore, board is actually your param name and the type should be `String[][]`.

```
public void makeBoard(String[][] Board,int column, int row){...}
```